# Unable to associate style with layer

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I'm trying to associate a previously created style with a layer, according to https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/styles.yaml, through a NodeJS code.

POSTing to:

> http://...:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/camada_de_estacoes_3/styles?default=true

Body:

```
{ name: "camada_de_estacoes_3", filename: "camada_de_estacoes_3.sld" }
```

PS1: yes, style with same name as layer;
PS2: also tried with "[workspace name]:" in front of names of things, no success;
PS3: Geoserver version 2.13.2.

Response: `status 500 - "name"`

What am I doing wrong?

Log piece:

> 2020-09-29 12:00:22,490 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - name
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: name at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
> at
> org.geoserver.config.util.SecureXStream$DetailedSecurityExceptionWrapper.realClass(SecureXStream.java:175)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:133)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
> at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1486) at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1466) at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1346) at
> org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister.load(XStreamPersister.java:667)
> at
> org.geoserver.rest.converters.XStreamJSONMessageConverter.readInternal(XStreamJSONMessageConverter.java:59)

(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems my `body` was missing a "root property" called `style`. The glue came from switching from "Example Value" to "Model" in the API documentation about this specific endpoint. So, `body` is now:

```
{ style: { name: "camada_de_estacoes_3" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue in version 2.19 of GeoServer.

I logged it as a bug on the GeoServer Jira board.
https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-10771